# Datepicker some problems with opening

Tags: javascript, jquery, tabs, datepicker

I use in my web app datepicker jquery but it I have some problem:
  I have two tabs in one of them I have two menu, were I use datepicker in each other of menu.
  And second tab has one menu and there I also use datepicker.
When I load my web page, and try to set some date with datepicker it is work (datepicker was opened). But after that I go to the second menu in this tab or another tab and try to set some date in my input date, but datepicker not opens. I also use ajax in this page.
Whats wrong? thx!

```
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <input type="text" name="dateTime" id="dateTime" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required />
  <script>
     $(function() {
       $("#dateTime").datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" , changeMonth: true });
     });
  </script>
```

Comment: And of course all these element with datepickers have the ID `#dateTime`, or did you use unique ID's for all the elements ?

Comment: Plz create a jsfiddle/jsbin because your problem is specific to you having tabs & there are no tabs in your code provided.

Comment: adeneo - no I used different names for Id's inputs, and write this script for each of them in menus pages. Now I changed it to same classname for all datepickers that I have in my app, but it work the same as work in the past.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the selector

`$("#dateTime")`

**ID in a page is supposed to be unique**

Use **classes instead.**

Because you are using a `ID selector` it tried to find the first instance of the element. Once it finds it, stops searching again. So it will never be applied to the element in the other tab..

Change

```
<input type="text" name="dateTime" id="dateTime"
```

to

```
<input type="text" name="dateTime" class="dateTime"
```

And then change the selector to

`$(".dateTime")`

Comment: I do it, but it also work only in first request to datepicker..I have same code in each of menupages in tab.